# protractor E2E TEST multiple file upload using ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ng-file-upload, e2e-testing

I was writing E2E test-case using protractor for angularjs application. My application has multiple file uploading as one of its features. So, to write E2E test-case for my application, I have to automate multiple file-uploading.

I am able to upload single file using protractor but my application requires more than 1 file for seamless working.

```
browser.get(localUrl);
var button = element(by.css('[ngf-select]'));
button.click();
var input = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
input.sendKeys([ absolutePath, absolutePath1, absolutePath2]);
```

[image: Image after performing button.click() operation]
Regards

Ajay

Comment: does your application as multiple upload buttons or it has only one using this button you need to upload multiple files?

Comment: if possible attach screenshot of UI for uploading functionality

Comment: @SureshSalloju Application have a single button to upload multiple files.

Comment: Implement a loop operation and put above code in it. it will do

Comment: @SureshSalloju can you please provide a pseudo code for implementing above functionality?

Comment: sure, give few minutes

Comment: Can please attach the screenshot after button.click(); operation?

Comment: @SureshSalloju. A file-selector is opened after button.click() operation. Please find screenshots in the question. How to upload multiple files using input.sendKeys() in ng-file-upload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

browser.get(localUrl);

```
var button = element(by.css('[ngf-select]'));

button.click();

var input = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));

input.sendKeys( absolutePath + "\n" + absolutePath1 + "\n" + absolutePath2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems to be like **Data Driven** approach. So, keep all input file paths in below function **arrayOfData()** and it block will iterate till all files are uploaded. You can follow the below code:

```
describe('Data driven test spec', function () { 
   function arrayOfData() {
     return [
          {
            "absolutePath": "/PathToFile1",
          },
          {
            "absolutePath": "/PathToFile2",
          },
          {
            "absolutePath": "/PathToFile3",
          }, 
      ]
    }

beforeAll(function(){
   browser.get(localUrl);
})

using(arrayofData, function (inputData) {
 it('test case logic to be executed for each set of data', function () {
     var button = element(by.css('[ngf-select]'));
     var input = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
     button.click();
     input.sendKeys(inputData.absolutePath);
   });
 });
});
```

Comment: Not working throwing angularjs error
Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/test"